# Ordering @future method

Tags: apex, future

is there any functionality in the salesforce that we can set order of the future methods?

someone just told me that we can do that and i was looking for that but  could not find any solution.

workaround i know : if any object is getting updated on one future method then we can write trigger to call another future method.

but is there any other way?

Note : i am just exploring this scenario for learning purpose.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If a trigger is run as a result of a future method you cannot then cause another future method to execute. This will throw an error that a future cannot be called from a future

Answer (score 5):

@future methods are enqueued in a message queue that doesn't guarantee order of delivery. While they will **often** run in the order they're enqueued in there's no guarantee of that, and out of order execution is certainly possible.

[Your idea of "chaining" future methods works better with Queuable jobs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm), since they can directly enqueue each other.

Also, for the sake of timing be aware that @future, Queueable, and other forms of async Apex are only enqueued for execution when the request that enqueued them completes since enqueued work is rolled back if the request fails.

Comment: "Also, for the sake of timing be aware that @future, Queueable, and other forms of async Apex are only enqueued for execution when the request that enqueued them completes since enqueued work is rolled back if the request fails." i did not get this. can you explain please. thanks

Comment: Queueables are also not ordered.
enqueue 10 jobs, they can all run at the same time, and you can get data contention.